# int('1.5') VS float('1.5') in python

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, int, valueerror

Why does `float('1.5')` gives `1.5` as output as expected but `int('1.5')` gives a value error?

Shouldn't python automatically convert the string into float and then into integer.

Comment: No, if you want to do that write `int(float('1.5'))`

Comment: @jonrsharpe i do know `int(float('1.5'))` works, i wanted to know the reason why `int('1.5')` is wrong

Comment: Because `'1.5'` isn't a string representing an integer literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `1.5` isn't a valid integer literal which is required by the `int()` function.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

> If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,
> bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in radix
> base.

Whereas integer literals are defined as follows:

```
integer      ::=  decinteger | bininteger | octinteger | hexinteger
decinteger   ::=  nonzerodigit (["_"] digit)* | "0"+ (["_"] "0")*
bininteger   ::=  "0" ("b" | "B") (["_"] bindigit)+
octinteger   ::=  "0" ("o" | "O") (["_"] octdigit)+
hexinteger   ::=  "0" ("x" | "X") (["_"] hexdigit)+
nonzerodigit ::=  "1"..."9"
digit        ::=  "0"..."9"
bindigit     ::=  "0" | "1"
octdigit     ::=  "0"..."7"
hexdigit     ::=  digit | "a"..."f" | "A"..."F"
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integers

Comment: Python 3.4 is fairly old (and past its end-of-life); I'd suggest updating your link to point to a newer version.

Comment: Here's an up-to-date reference: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals. Note that it's not  exactly the same, since Python now supports underscores in integer literals.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks, I've updated the table and URLs!